Spring coroutines AOP is not compatible with @Transactional
When using Spring Coroutine AOP, if the @transactional annotation and a custom AOP are applied together without specifying an order in the Aspect, there is an issue where the custom AOP does not get applied.
@Service
class TargetService() {
    private val log = KotlinLogging.logger { }

    @Logging
    @Transactional
    suspend fun aop(): String {
        delay(100)
        log.info { "aop target method call" }

        return "ok"
    }
}

@Aspect
//@Order(1)
@Component
class LoggingAspect {

    private val log = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @Around("@annotation(com.example.aopwithtransaction.aop.Logging)")
    fun logging(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
        return mono {
            log.info { "Aop Logging started" }

            val result = joinPoint.proceed().let { result ->
                if (result is Mono<*>) {
                    result.awaitSingleOrNull()
                } else {
                    result
                }
            }

            log.info { "Aop Logging completed" }

            result
        }
    }
}

In cases like the one above, the custom AOP does not function unless the order is specified, in which case it does function.
This is a simple example : https://github.com/backtony/spring-reactive-aop-transaction

Please check if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/68590809/1082681. See also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23575.
